# Radio buttons next to each other?

Tags: html, css

I wanted to know how to put a radio button next to another radio button in a more simple way. I am learning CSS but I cannot figure out yet how to do it. My actual code is the next one:

```html
<form action="evaluacion.php" method="post" id="test">
  Coloca el simbolo de magnitud correcto: <br><br> ¿Cuál es el símbolo de magnitud correcto de la longitud?
  <br>
  <div>
    <input type="radio" name="pregunta1" id="pregunta1rA" value="A" required/>
    <label for="pregunta1ra">T</label>
    <br>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="radio" name="pregunta1" id="pregunta1rB" value="B" required/>
    <label for="pregunta1rb">J</label>
    <br>

  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="radio" name="pregunta1" id="pregunta1rC" value="C" required/>
    <label for="pregunta1rc">N</label>
    <br>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Enviar respuestas"><br><br><br>
</form>
```

And my current CSS is this one: `div { display: inline-block;}`

This is my current code but I want to know if there is a better way to the inline sentence without using a lot of "div"

Comment: Remove BR tags...

Comment: as i can see answer is already given but for your reference `br` tag is for single line break and is used for achieving breaks between elements

Comment: I appreciate all the information given. Thank you for the clarification!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The br tags were the ones breaking it. You can accomplish this without any divs.

```
<body> 

<form action="evaluacion.php" method="post" id="test">

    Coloca el simbolo de magnitud correcto: <br><br>
    ¿Cuál es el símbolo de magnitud correcto de la longitud?

    <br>
        <input type="radio" name="pregunta1" id="pregunta1rA" value="A" required/>
        <label for="pregunta1ra">T</label>

        <input type="radio" name="pregunta1" id="pregunta1rB" value="B" required/>
        <label for="pregunta1rb">J</label>

        <input type="radio" name="pregunta1" id="pregunta1rC" value="C" required/>
        <label for="pregunta1rc" >N</label>
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar respuestas"><br><br><br>
</form>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2k05eLjh/

In general if you do need a wrapper for something like this, you can look into wrapping a set instead of each individual item before resorting to that.